# is it possible to truncate sys_file_processedfile?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am stuck with a `sys_file_processedfile` table with more than 200.000 entries. Is it possible to truncate the table and empty the folder `/fileadmin/_processed_` without destroying something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

In Admin Tools (Installtool) under Maintenance there is a card named `Remove Temporary Assets` which you should use to do so.

> TYPO3 stores processed files and cached images in a dedicated directory. This directory is likely to grow quickly.
>
> With this action you can delete the files in this folder. Afterwards, you should also clear the cache database tables.
>
> The File Abstraction Layer additionally stores a database record for every file it needs to process. (e.g. image thumbnails). In case you modified some graphics settings (All Configuration [GFX]) and you need all processed files to get regenerated, you can use this tool to remove the "*processed*" ones.

Comment: Be careful. On a production server, removing all the processed files can lead to a heavy cpu load, because all the images will need to be processed again. Php processes will take more resources and more time to complete, and depending on the traffic, this can saturate the php-fpm pool.